# How to link to user's profile on django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have been trying to link to user's profile page but everytime I try it, it returns a 404 error. I dont know but maybe the error is on the urls.py file.

views.py

```
    def profile(request, username=None):
      if username:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

      else:
        post_owner = request.user

      args1 = {
        'post_owner': post_owner,
      }
      return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
      path('<str:username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
      path('login', views.login, name='login'),
      path('register', views.register, name='register'),
      path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),

    ]
```

index.html

```
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ request.user }}">{{ user.username }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link it with:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ request.user.username }}">{{ user.username }}</a>
```

but better would be to use an [**`{% url … }`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' username=request.user.username %}">{{ user.username }}</a>
```

Your paths also overlap, this means that you will *never* be able to access `login`, `register` or `logout`, since the first path will "fire" with the idea that `username='login'`.

You better define *non-overlapping* paths, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<str:username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: Hey Williem thank you, is there any way I can link to the profile page without the `profile/` on the url?

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala: you don't need to prepend the part with `profile/` you simply need to make the paths non-overlapping. You can do that in all possible ways, for example adding a prefix to `login/`, `logout/`, etc. since `str:` does not allow a slash anyway. But right now noone can login/logout/register on your site :)

Comment: Ok so I have an index.html that has a navbar and it is connected to a css, what can I do to extend the template to other html without using the same css link? I need to have everything organised so I want to have a css per html

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala: you can pass a parameter to the template. But it looks quite *odd* to have a separate css file per html file, the idea of a css file is to "reuse" it, otherwise you can define the style in a `<style>` flag.

Comment: `urlpatterns` is OK but `path('<str:username>/' ...` must be last. Also urls on Facebook and my website Speedy Net use similar paths.

Comment: @Uri: then what if there is a user with `username='logout'`, `username='register'`, and `username='login`'? These people should not be able to see their profile?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You have to define usernames which are not allowed in the website, such as `logout`.

Comment: @Uri: this looks like "ugly" software design. It would take a lot of effort to compile the list of usernames, it can be tricky. Actually the above is already problematic, since a `str:` can not contain a slash, so usernames with a slash are not allowed as well. It thus makes it very combersome to find the list of patterns :). Usually if you define a type, then you should make it so that it restricts invalid types, a string can not do that. Furthermore it would require taking a look at the invalid users each time when you define new patterns.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem All I can say is that it works for Facebook. The most popular social network in the world. And my website, for example https://en.speedy.net/uri-rodberg/ is my public profile in English, which is designed similar to the `username` concept of Facebook. If something works for Facebook, you can't say it's not a good idea - there is a reason why Facebook is so popular.

Comment: @Uri: I don't think that the reason why Facebook is so popular is because of its URL patterns, I found it suprising to find out a lot of people never heart of a URL in the first place :). After all, it was mainly popular. It also (luckily) does not work with Django technology, but the core works with Haskell, which is a more rich programming language, since it gurantees pure functions and reproducability: https://github.com/facebook/Haxl

Comment: @Uri: furthermore facebook allows as far as I know that you specify a path for your user page, but that is not per se the username, you enter that, and it checks if it is still available, so you "decouple" the username from the path.

Comment: In Facebook pages and users both have optional usernames, such as `urirodberg`, which links to https://www.facebook.com/urirodberg - just like in Speedy Net. I don't see any flaw with such a design.

Comment: And by the way also Twitter, Instagram have the same URL patterns.

Comment: @Uri: the point is that it *decouples* it from the user, whereas in Django, the standard user model has a *required* username. As said, if you do not present the URL patterns properly, then it results in trouble, since here one can not make use of a slash. Often what is used is a slug in Django, but even then it would probably be advsiable to make it non-overlapping.

Comment: In Speedy Net it's a slug.

Answer (score 1):

"@Willem Van Onsem" has given perfectly correct answer. But one thing I want to add is to prevent the overlap. You can rearrange the rules and put that rule at bottom of all rules. because django checks the rule from top to bottom and stop matching when first match is found.

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
        path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
        path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),

        path('<str:username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
 ]
```

things should work fine.
But, as commented, we have to put validation that user can't use username from any above path name, like login, register or logout.
Also, would like to suggest that don't use these kind of patterns, instead use at least small prefixes like `u/<profile>` or `u/<id>` etc, which can be seen in many existing applications like gmail.

Comment: I think you should warn here that the users can not have `login`, `logout`, or `register` as username. This is actually one of the reasons why I would advise against this.

Comment: I also think that `path('<str:username>/', ...` is a completely legitimate pattern, but it must be the last.